# How to send a http request in Visual Studio's Post-build event

Tags: visual-studio, post-build

I am working on a Asp.net web form project. After build, when I open `http://localhost/myProject/page1.aspx`,  It will take about 10 seconds to warm up the project.

I want VS send a http request to `http://localhost/myProject/` automatically every time I build. The Post-Build event looks like a good place, but don't know how. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

put this into Post-Build event command line:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -Command iwr localhost/myProject
```

iwr = invoke-WebRequest.